# How to populate column data in one table based on an id match from another table (using the data from the matched table)

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

In Oracle I have two tables. Both are populated with data and have a `timestamp` column.

One table has that column filled with data, the other table doesn't. But I need to get the data from the table that does into the column of the other table based on a match of another column.

Each has 'code' so the timestamp from the one table should only be put in the timestamp of the other table where the codes match.

I've tried cursors etc, but it seems like I'm missing something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `code` a primary key or unique column in the source table?

Comment: it's not a primary key, it's nullable, and I'm pretty sure it's not unique

Comment: Then what do you do when two codes match?

Comment: put the timestamp from the one table into the other from the row with matching codes

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I'll try again. What do you do when two rows from the source table match the same code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a correlated update.  This will update every row of `destinationTable` with the `timestamp_col` from `sourceTable` where there is a match on the `code` column.

```
UPDATE destinationTable d
   SET timestamp_col = (SELECT s.timestamp_col
                          FROM sourceTable s 
                         WHERE s.code = d.code )
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM sourceTable s
                WHERE s.code = d.code )
```

Comment: This will most probably fail as the code column can contain duplicates (see comments to the question). You probably need a `max(s.timestamp_col)` or something similar in the sub-select.

Comment: this seems like the way to go... but we're dealing with about 30 million rows.. so we're going to do some other stuff to speed it up first... with this number in mind... do you suggest anything else?

Comment: @redBarron - A single `UPDATE` statement is going to be the most efficient way to update a large number of rows.  As @Neil and @a_horse_with_no_name are pointing out, if there can be multiple rows with the same `code`, you'll need to specify additional criteria to figure out which row from the source table to use to update any particular row in the destination table (possibly with the `max(s.timestamp_col)`).

Comment: thanks Neil and Justin... I made indexes on the columns and ran the code above with max().. and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I think I would have done something like this (untested), if the destination has a primary key or unique column:

```
UPDATE (
  SELECT d.primary_key AS pk, d.timestamp_col AS dest_col, MAX(s.timestamp_col) AS src_col
    FROM dest d
    JOIN src s ON d.code = s.code
    GROUP BY pk, dest_col
  ) j
  SET j.dest_col = j.src_col
```